# How to compare MotionEvent coordinates to original image coordinates?

Tags: android

I have an image (`ImageView`). I have certain areas on the image. When a use taps the screen, I want to detect which area was selected.

I have identified the area boundaries on the original image, but the x and y of `MotionEvent` are off.

I tried dip-to-pixel conversion (`TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dipValue, metrics)`), but they are still off. It certainly has to do with the screen size / density / etc., but how exactly to get the pixel value of the touch event for the original image? (or, vice-versa - how to convert the original image coordinates to something that is comparable with the x and y of the motion event)

Comment: Have a look at this project https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap

Comment: play with ImageView.getImageMatrix()

Answer (score 0):

I managed to calculate it using the right and bottom coordinates of the `ImageView` (`pic`) compared to the real image size (568x1207).

```
float xCoef = 568f / pic.getRight();
float yCoef = 1207f / pic.getBottom();
float x = event.getX() * xCoef;
float y = event.getY() * yCoef;
```

Comment: this is not how it should be done, again, use ImageView.getImageMatrix()

Comment: how? I tried to map points (`matrix.mapPoints(new float[] {eventX, eventY}`, but the results were not correct.

Comment: they are correct, the point (0, 0) is mapped to the physical point where left-top pixel is drawn, if you want reverse mapping use invert()ed Matrix

Comment: I don't want reverse mapping, and 0,0 is always 0,0. But when clkcing on the bottom-right corner I get x,y=540,830, and when I run matrix.mapPoints, I get x,y=317,390. And I want to get 568,1207, which is the bottom-right corner of the actual image

Comment: ok so you need reverse mapping: from. view coords to bitmap coords, use then Matrix.invert(invertedMatrix)

Comment: Matrix m = pic.getImageMatrix();
Matrix inverted = new Matrix();
m.invert(inverted);
float[] point = new float[] {event.getX(), event.getY()};
inverted.mapPoints(point);

result: still wrong - x,y= 969.3,1774.78